# How to have Text that wraps, has a maximum height, and becomes scrollable if the text goes over that maxiumum height?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to set up a `Text` component that has a maximum height of the window's height divided by three. The source of the text gives it as a single line, so it also needs to wrap once its width exceeds that of the window. Finally, I'd like the text to become scrollable if its height exceeds 1/3 of the window's.

I've also got a `ListView` below it, and I want the top of the `ListView` to be right at the bottom of the `Text`.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    // anchors.margins: 10

    ScrollView {
        id: descriptionBox
        clip: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height / 3
        contentWidth: parent.width

        Text {
            id: descriptionBoxLabel
            text: "Eum id neque possimus inventore similique. Et dolores exercitationem vel dignissimos. Voluptatibus assumenda veniam consequuntur. Harum reprehenderit tempora nostrum. Assumenda unde omnis non sit minima voluptas eligendi eum."
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: useListView
        model: ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
        delegate: CheckDelegate {
            text: modelData
            width: Window.width - 20
        }

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
    }
}
```

This kind of works, but the `Text` doesn't become scrollable when I shrink the height of the window, and the top of the `ListView` isn't lined up with the bottom of the `Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the original issue is, but, I reworked it to use a `Flickable` instead of a `ScrollView`. The difference being you have to be meticulous in setting `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` correctly for the `ScrollBar` to work. I also tweaked the width calculation of your `ListView` delegate to follow the width of the `ListView`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Flickable {
            id: descriptionBox
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: Math.min(parent.height / 3, frame.height)
            clip: true
            contentWidth: frame.width
            contentHeight: frame.height
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                width: 20
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }            
            Frame {
                id: frame
                width: descriptionBox.width - 20
                Text {
                    id: descriptionBoxLabel
                    text: "Eum id neque possimus inventore similique. Et dolores exercitationem vel dignissimos. Voluptatibus assumenda veniam consequuntur. Harum reprehenderit tempora nostrum. Assumenda unde omnis non sit minima voluptas eligendi eum."
                    width: parent.width
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                }
            }
        }
        
        ListView {
            id: useListView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
            delegate: CheckDelegate {
                text: modelData
                width: ListView.view.width - 20
            }
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                width: 20
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

[EDIT]

To eliminate the white space, modified the `Layout` height with:

```
Layout.preferredHeight: Math.min(parent.height / 3, frame.height)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works almost perfectly. It still has a space in between the Text and ListView that grows with the window height, though. How can I fix that?

https://i.imgur.com/ZSSBKqK.png

Comment: Oh! I get it. I changed the tweaked the answer - hopefully it is what you want.